# How to make Terminator terminal emulator transparent in dwm?

Tags: linux, transparency, ubuntu-20.04, dwm, terminator

How to make window transparency for Terminator terminal emulator work with dwm?

I've set background transparency inside Terminator settings. It works with ordinary Ubuntu 20.04 windows manager, but with dwm it doesn't work.

How to make Terminator terminal emulator transparent in dwm?

Answer (score -1):

Dwm has a patch on suckless.org/dwm go to patches and default transparency. Download the patch to dwm source directory. patch -p1 < path/to/patch.diff. Remake dwm and start again see if it works. If it doesn't you need a compositor. I prefer xcompmgr in .xinitrc, Cheers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaRzOEoyR4s

Comment: That transparency for all window, but there's config for xterm or uxterm which makes only terminal transparent, I had it done before, but I can't find a config